# Stream of fibonacci sequence in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm currently trying to understand the concept of streams in scheme. As an example I'm supposed to write a function `fibonacci` that returns fibonacci numbers as a stream representation.

The desired output/usage of the function looks like this:

```
> (define a (finbonacci))
> a
((0 0) . #<promise>)
> (tail a)
((1 1) . #<promise>)
> (tail (tail a))
((2 1) . #<promise>)
```

So each stream element represents a pair of `n fib(n)`.

A stream is pre-defined like this:

```
(define the-empty-stream '())

(define-syntax cons-stream
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((cons-stream x y)
     (cons x (delay y)))))

(define head car)
(define (tail s) (force (cdr s)))
(define empty-stream? null?)
```

My current very basic attempt for a solution is the following:

```
(define fibo
    (cons-stream 1
                 (cons-stream 1
                              (map + fibo (tail fibo))))))
```

But even if this would calculate anything, I would not know how to pass `n` into the output or the following stream.

Comment: How does this solution work? I'm confused how `let` works here. I guess the three initial value of the parameters of `f` will be "overidden"  when calling `f` again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right path. The only thing that needs to be adjusted is the precise formulation of the recursive definition.

Consider the following (where --- means we are adding):

```
1 1 2 3 5   8  ...   fib
1 2 3 5 8  13  ...   (stream-rest fib)
------------------   ---------------------------------
2 3 5 8 13 21  ...   (stream-rest (stream-rest fib))
```

Note that `(stream-rest (stream-rest fib))` is the sum of `fib` and `(stream-rest fib)`.
That means that we can define `fib` as:

```
(define fib (stream-cons 1 (stream-cons 1 (stream-add fib (stream-rest fib)))))
```